# Custom config.js not initialized when adding custom block, but appears on refresh

Tags: ckeditor, magnolia

I'm trying to add an extra block type in the stories app, I've managed to do so. Here's the YAML definition:

```
class: info.magnolia.editor.block.stock.FieldSetBlockDefinition
templateId: content-components:blocks/storyText
icon: content-item
fields:
  storyText:
    class: info.magnolia.ui.form.field.definition.RichTextFieldDefinition
    configJsFile: /.resources/assets/js/ckEditorConfigStory.js
    label: Rich text
```

This works fine except the custom JS config is not initialized at first.

When entering the content editor app and adding this new block type, it's not rendering the CKEditor, however, if I refresh the page after the block has been created, it works.

I believe this might be a bug but maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1):

What do your magnolia.properties look like? You might need to look at `magnolia.develop` [here](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/docs61/Configuration+management).  What version of Magnolia are you using?

Comment: magnolia.develop is set to false, and from my understanding it should stay that way since the performance might be affected. We're using 5.7.2 and will switch to 6 when 6.3 gets out. I've sent a mail to someone from the Magnolia team because I believe this might be a bug.

Comment: `magnolia.develop` can be `true` while developing, to fix the problem you are talking about (you'd need to restart Magnolia after changing this property): ```    Enable ClasspathScanner, when developing via IDE and changing / deploying edited classpath based resources.
    Disable the cache for resources.```

Comment: We solved it, the issue came from the fact that we were using 5.7.2, we switched to 5.7.5 and it fixed it. From the docs: Note that RichTextFieldDefinition, based on the CKEditor, is supported in the Content editor since Magnolia 5.7.3.

Answer (score 0):

Richtext field with CKeditor is supported from 5.7.3 and up, we were using 5.7.2, upgrading to 5.7.5 fixed the issue.

> Note that RichTextFieldDefinition, based on the CKEditor, is supported in the Content editor since Magnolia 5.7.3.

[From the docs](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS57/Developing+and+rendering+custom+content+blocks)